# Does Lore have a penis?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

I just finished watching [TNG: "Datalore"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Datalore_(episode)). When they found Lore's body parts I saw no genitals.

[image: Members of the crew open up a cupboard, steam comes out to reveal moulds holding Lore's body parts separately from each other]

If Data was built after why would Soong put them on him but not B-4 and Lore? Lore is basically the same as Data so why would he not put them on Lore?

Comment: I would imagine that they were simply out of of the camera frame.

Comment: Or intentionally not put on the "parts" for the shot because network TV.

Comment: You can't see any genitals cause his pelvis is facing the wrong way.  That's his ass there on the bottom right.  If he's got a dick, it's on the other side.

Comment: if lore is indeed dickless the most likely explanation would be that he himself removed it to be edgy and rebellious.

Comment: Yes. And a vagina. This was the episode originally titled _the best of both worlds_

Comment: Come to think of it, it's strange that his is the only penis we don't see on the show.

Answer (score 9):

In-universe, it's not made clear whether Lore does or doesn't have genitalia, but the fact that Lore is confident that he can pass for Data, and the fact that no-one comments on this fairly major anatomical difference when they're discussing Data and Lore's capacities would strongly suggest that Lore is also *anatomically correct* and in every other way largely identical to Lore save for a few inconsequential differences (removable ears, for example).

Additionally, when we see him disassembled, his groin is facing into the foam padding. It's likely that having his lower half packed this way was an intentional packing choice on the part of Soong, who we know was keen to preserve the modesty of his robots from the other colonists. There are also parts of him, including his right hand, that are out of frame entirely and not seen until later scenes *after he's been assembled*.

[image: A collage of two images; on the left: The sections of Lore's body from the cupboard cropped and pieced together to show where they go; the right forearm and hand is missing and the groin area is facing into the mould with the buttocks out. And on the right: A top down view of Lore on a workbench with a device over his chest and a panel open for working]

---

Out-of-universe, you can't show a penis on Network Television on a prime time show aimed at children.

> Material is indecent if, in context, it depicts or describes sexual or
> excretory organs or activities in terms patently offensive as measured
> by contemporary community standards for the broadcast medium.
>
> <sub><sup>[FCC Guidelines](https://www.fcc.gov/reports-research/guides/obscenity-indecency-profanity-faq)</sup></sub>